# Using ServiceBusTrigger in the Webjobs SDK 3.x, can the Singleton attribute use a UserProperty as the scope?

Tags: azure-webjobs, servicebus, azure-webjobs-triggered

I am using a `ServiceBusTrigger` to execute code when receiving a message.  I would like to use the [Singleton attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#singleton-attribute) to limit which messages can be executed in parallel.  This attribute allows specifying a scope bound to properties on the incoming message, such that messages with different values can be executed in parallel but ones with the same value must be done serially.

This works when using top level properties on the incoming message object like CorrelationId.

Example

```
[Singleton("{CorrelationId}", SingletonScope.Function, Mode = SingletonMode.Function)]
public async Task HandleMessage(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("my-topic-name", "my-subscription-name"), ServiceBusAccount("my-account-name")]
    Message message,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
{
    await Task.Yield();
}
```

What I am struggling to figure out is how to achieve the same behavior with user properties on the message.  These are stored in the `UserProperties` dictionary on the `Message` object. I'm not seeing a way to refer to these with the binding statement in the `Singleton` attribute, but it seems like this would be a very common use case when combining `Singleton` with `ServiceBusTrigger`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Service Bus Bindings exposes [Message Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#message-metadata) in binding expressions. So, `userProperties.<key>` should do the trick.

Comment: The dot notation for the properties inside the UserProperties dictionary works.