# Supported bindings for Singleton scopeId on HTTP Trigger Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I am unclear on how the `scopeId` parameter of the `SingletonAttribute` works. Specifically does the `scopeId` parameter work for HTTP Trigger Azure Functions when you bind it to a route parameter? How does the binding work? What variables/values can I bind to?

For example:

```cs
[Singleton("{input}", Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "v1/{input:length(1,30)}")] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest req, string input, ILogger log) {
    return new OkObjectResult(input + " world");
}
```

A HTTP POST request to this function with the URI 'v1/hello' would return: "Hello world".

But would the Singleton attribute work such that all requests to 'v1/hello' would run serially whereas two simultaneous requests with one to 'v1/first' and the other to 'v1/second' would run in parallel?

I see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732290/using-servicebustrigger-in-the-webjobs-sdk-3-x-can-the-singleton-attribute-use) that for Service Bus Triggers you can bind to properties *within* the Message object directly.
Also in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#scope-values) there is an example of a Queue Trigger Function with scopeId binding to a property in the WorkItem object.
It's unclear what's supported for HTTP Trigger Functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from Microsoft on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/69011#issuecomment-771922910

"Binding expressions for **Singleton** have the same behavior as those for general input/output bindings. That is, any binding data from the trigger is available for reference.

In the case of HttpTrigger, that includes any POCO members if you’re binding to a POCO type, as well as any route parameters.
In regards to your code, `SingletonMode.Listener` is not what you want for your requirement. If you're just trying to serialize individual invocations of the function then you should use the default mode, i.e. `[Singleton(“{input}”)]`.

To answer your question – yes, this would serialize all invocations of v1/hello, allowing v1/first and v1/second to run concurrently."

Answer (score 0):

**You have two ways to implement singleton mode in Azure function.**

**The first:**

You can do this by setting `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` or `maxConcurrentCalls`.

[Singleton Azure function running as separate instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001149/singleton-azure-function-running-as-separate-instances)

**The second type:**

Create a complete Function project, similar to webapp, and implement it in `Configure`.

[Use dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#service-lifetimes)

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService>((s) => {
            return new MyService();
        });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't answer my question

Comment: @davekats I mean no attribute like you said to set singleton.